# Reporting progress of parser

Tags: java, antlr, progress, antlr4

I have a large file that I am trying to parse with Antlr in Java, and I would like to show the progress.

It looked like could do the following:

```
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
int maxTokenIndex = tokens.size();
```

and then use `maxTokenIndex` in a `ParseTreeListener` as such:

```
public void exitMyRule(MyRuleContext context) {
    int tokenIndex = context.start.getTokenIndex();
    myReportProgress(tokenIndex, maxTokenIndex);
}
```

The second half of that appears to work.  I get ever increasing values for `tokenIndex`.  However, `tokens.size()` is returning 0.  This makes it impossible to gauge how much progress I have made.

Is there a good way to get an estimate of how far along I am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following appears to work.

```
File file = getFile();
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(new FileReader(file));
ProgressMonitor progress = new ProgressMonitor(null,
                                               "Loading " + file.getName(),
                                               null,
                                               0,
                                               input.size());
```

Then extend `MyGrammarBaseListener` with

```
@Override 
public void exitMyRule(MyRuleContext context) {
    progress.setProgress(context.stop.getStopIndex());
}
```